# Django crudbuilder & Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

```
Django==1.11.7
django-crudbuilder==0.2.5
```

Using [Bootstrap datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker). Now trying to use the datepicker in a crud form for a date field.

In a normal Django form, this would work:

```
self.fields['payment_date'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'datepicker'})
```

But how can the `class:datepicker` be set for a particular field in a crud form?

The [documentation](http://django-crudbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=css&check_keywords=yes&area=default#) doesn't seem to mention anything useful on `css` or `html` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with implementing custom templates.

Copy over the instance templates in `crudbuilder/templates/crudbuilder/instance/` into your application template directory.

Replace the template location for the included form template in all the copied over instance templates .e.g. [create.html](https://github.com/asifpy/django-crudbuilder/blob/0.2.7/crudbuilder/templates/crudbuilder/instance/create.html)

```
...

{% block main_content %}

<div class='container'>
    <h3>Create {{actual_model_name|title}}</h3>
    <hr/>
    {% include "my_app/widgets/form.html" %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

In `my_app/templates/my_app/widgets/form.html`, write this instead to set the datepicker class on payment_date. (Original code was copied from [django-cruid](https://github.com/asifpy/django-crudbuilder/blob/0.2.7/crudbuilder/templates/crudbuilder/widgets/form.html))

```
{% load crudbuilder %}
{% include "datepicker.html" %}

<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <fieldset class={% if field.errors %} "form-group has-error" {% else %} "form-group" {% endif %} >
            {{ field|label_with_class:"col-sm-2 control-label" }}
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                {% if field.name == 'payment_date' %}
                     {{ field|input_with_class:"form-control datepicker" }}
                {% endif %} 
                {{ field|input_with_class:"form-control" }}
                {{ field.errors }}
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div  class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-12">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Finally, set your crud form to [use your custom templates](https://django-crudbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html#use-your-own-html-templates-for-crudbuilder).

```
class PersonCrud(BaseCrudBuilder):
    ...
    custom_templates = {
        'list': 'my_app/list.html',
        'create': 'my_app/create.html',
        'detail': 'my_app/detail.html',
        'update': 'my_app/update.html',
        'delete': 'my_app/delete.html'
    }
```

Comment: Obviously, `{% include "datepicker.html" %}` needs to be added to the template (or base template) as well. When this is added, above solution works fine. Thx!

Comment: @Davy Thank you for pointing that out. If you edit this answer include this information, I'll approve your edit.